# results pure SQL differ from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a pure SQL command:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, COUNT(ColumnB), SUM(ColumnC) FROM Table WHERE ColumnA=i GROUP BY ColumnB
```

that works fine.

I tried to translate into SqlAlchemy:

```
db.session.query(Table.ColumnA, Table.ColumnB, func.count(Table.ColumnB), func.sum(Table.ColumnB)).filter(Table.ColumnA==i).order_by(Table.ColumnB)
```

but the results differ. The SqlAlchemy statement just return the first 'ColumnA, ColumnB' combination.
Putting the pure Sql statement into db.session.execute() it works fine too.

What's my fail?

Comment: `filter(Table.ColumnA)` will render as `WHERE table_name.ColumnA` and will return rows where the value in ColumnA is "true" when (implicitly) converted to a boolean. If you want to filter on rows where ColumnA is equal to a particular value then use `filter(Table.ColumnA == some_value)`

Comment: sorry, you are right. My question was not correct. Obviously, i use Table.ColumnA == i. The result should give many records back with ColumnA, ColumnB combination and sum, count values, but this query return just the first combination.

Comment: You are using `order_by`, did you mean `group_by`?

Comment: Oops, i a newbie in sqlalchemy. Though (or read) order_by is the equivalent to SLQ group - Thanks, that's simple.